# Temporal gap in time series

Tags: time-series

I want to predict the demand for a product. For this I have a dataset with 2 columns. Day in date format and quantity where the demanded units of that product per day are indicated.

The data are daily and belong to the years 2018 to June 2023, but there are no records for the year 2020, so I have an important gap. I think this may influence when working with time series and trying to make predictions.

How could I deal with this? I have read that one possible way is to add a new binary variable where 1 is if there is data and 0 otherwise, but I don't know if this is correct or what better ways there are to treat the data in these cases.

I would like to know some techniques that allow a good treatment of the data in these cases before applying a model. I don't need a solution to the specific problem but I need to get approaches to this.

If you need to provide any further data or information, please let me know and we can discuss it.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have different solutions depending on the size of the gap and the datapoints.

If the gap is small I would recommend to do a Time Series Imputation.
In a nutshell it tries to impute the values depending on your previous results.

Some examples:

In R you could use the imputeTS package:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/imputeTS/vignettes/imputeTS-Time-Series-Missing-Value-Imputation-in-R.pdf

Survey on TS-Imputation:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.11347

---

Depending on the data you have you can also create Labeling functions. This approach is called Weak-Supervision and generally works with a mixture of labeled and unlabeled data. A library you can use is snorkel.

https://www.snorkel.org/

However I find this most useful with gaps you can fill in with a binary approach. Labeling data that is numerical is a very hard task.

---

Furthermore there are different imputation strategies. They should be included in the imputeTS R-Package as well.

A good read: [https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/defining-analysing-and-implementing-imputation-techniques/#:~:text=Imputation%20is%20a%20technique%20used,data%2Finformation%20of%20the%20dataset](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/defining-analysing-and-implementing-imputation-techniques/#:%7E:text=Imputation%20is%20a%20technique%20used,data%2Finformation%20of%20the%20dataset).

---

You could also train a neural network predicting the results for 2020. For that you can choose whatever architecture works the best. I've had great results with predicting numerical values in regression problems by using a 1 Dimensional CNN.

---

Another method is to train the data regardless of the gap and exclude the time. You wouldn't have a real time-series there, rather a Neural Network trying to find a regression function solely based on the data with no temporal dimension.

---

Keep in mind that no technique is perfect. What might work for someone else doesn't have to be the best solution for your problem. The data imputed or predicted is no real data and will always have an effect on the prediction since you can't predict numbers with 100% confidence.